# Period space amChart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I use the library [amchart](https://www.amcharts.com/) to generate a chart with the plugin [dataLoader](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/using-data-loader-plugin/)
. But each time there is one day empty at the begin and the end of the chart for no reason. Did someone already get this error?

[image]

-- EDIT FIDDLE --

I create a fiddle using the example data from amchart that you can find [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/stock-comparing-external-data-v3/). I just change the chart type to "line" and the default period to "10D" and as you can see there is still a space on the right of the chart (if also at left as well if you change the period). Is it possible to erase it?

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
"theme": "none",

  //"color": "#fff",
  "dataSets": [ {
    "title": "MSFT",
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "Open",
      "toField": "open"
    }, {
      "fromField": "High",
      "toField": "high"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Low",
      "toField": "low"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Close",
      "toField": "close"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Volume",
      "toField": "volume"
    } ],
    "compared": false,
    "categoryField": "Date",

    /**
     * data loader for data set data
     */
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/assets/stock/MSFT.csv",
      "format": "csv",
      "showCurtain": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "async": true,
      "reverse": true,
      "delimiter": ",",
      "useColumnNames": true
    },

    /**
     * data loader for events data
     */
    "eventDataLoader": {
      "url": "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/assets/stock/MSFT_events.csv",
      "format": "csv",
      "showCurtain": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "async": true,
      "reverse": true,
      "delimiter": ",",
      "useColumnNames": true,
      "postProcess": function( data ) {
        for ( var x in data ) {
          switch ( data[ x ].Type ) {
            case 'A':
              var color = "#85CDE6";
              break;
            default:
              var color = "#cccccc";
              break;
          }
          data[ x ] = {
            "type": "pin",
            "graph": "g1",
            "backgroundColor": color,
            "date": data[ x ].Date,
            "text": data[ x ].Type,
            "description": "<strong>" + data[ x ].Title + "</strong><br />" + data[ x ].Description
          };
        }
        return data;
      }
    }

  }, {
    "title": "TXN",
    "fieldMappings": [ {
      "fromField": "Open",
      "toField": "open"
    }, {
      "fromField": "High",
      "toField": "high"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Low",
      "toField": "low"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Close",
      "toField": "close"
    }, {
      "fromField": "Volume",
      "toField": "volume"
    } ],
    "compared": true,
    "categoryField": "Date",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/assets/stock/TXN.csv",
      "format": "csv",
      "showCurtain": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "async": true,
      "reverse": true,
      "delimiter": ",",
      "useColumnNames": true
    }
  } ],
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",

  "panels": [ {
      "title": "Value",
      "percentHeight": 70,

      "stockGraphs": [ {
        "type": "line",
        "id": "g1",
        "openField": "open",
        "closeField": "close",
        "highField": "high",
        "lowField": "low",
        "valueField": "close",
        "lineColor": "#fff",
        "fillColors": "#fff",
        "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
        "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "comparedGraphLineThickness": 2,
        "columnWidth": 0.7,
        "useDataSetColors": false,
        "comparable": true,
        "compareField": "close",
        "showBalloon": false,
        "proCandlesticks": true
      } ],

      "stockLegend": {
        "valueTextRegular": undefined,
        "periodValueTextComparing": "[[percents.value.close]]%"
      }

    },

    {
      "title": "Volume",
      "percentHeight": 30,
      "marginTop": 1,
      "columnWidth": 0.6,
      "showCategoryAxis": false,

      "stockGraphs": [ {
        "valueField": "volume",
        "openField": "open",
        "type": "column",
        "showBalloon": false,
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "lineColor": "#fff",
        "fillColors": "#fff",
        "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
        "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
        "useDataSetColors": false
      } ],

      "stockLegend": {
        "markerType": "none",
        "markerSize": 0,
        "labelText": "",
        "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
      },

      "valueAxes": [ {
        "usePrefixes": true
      } ]
    }
  ],

  "panelsSettings": {
    //    "color": "#fff",
    "plotAreaFillColors": "#333",
    "plotAreaFillAlphas": 1,
    "marginLeft": 60,
    "marginTop": 5,
    "marginBottom": 5
  },

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "usePeriod": "WW",
    "backgroundColor": "#333",
    "graphFillColor": "#666",
    "graphFillAlpha": 0.5,
    "gridColor": "#555",
    "gridAlpha": 1,
    "selectedBackgroundColor": "#444",
    "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 1
  },

  "categoryAxesSettings": {
    "equalSpacing": true,
    "gridColor": "#555",
    "gridAlpha": 1
  },

  "valueAxesSettings": {
    "gridColor": "#555",
    "gridAlpha": 1,
    "inside": false,
    "showLastLabel": true
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "pan": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },

  "legendSettings": {
    //"color": "#fff"
  },

  "stockEventsSettings": {
    "showAt": "high",
    "type": "pin"
  },

  "balloon": {
    "textAlign": "left",
    "offsetY": 10
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "position": "bottom",
    "periods": [ {
        "period": "DD",
        "count": 10,
        "label": "10D",
        "selected": true
      }, {
        "period": "MM",
        "count": 1,
        "label": "1M"
      }, {
        "period": "MM",
        "count": 6,
        "label": "6M"
      }, {
        "period": "YYYY",
        "count": 1,
        "label": "1Y"
      }, {
        "period": "YYYY",
        "count": 2,
        "label": "2Y"
      },
      /* {
           "period": "YTD",
           "label": "YTD"
         },*/
      {
        "period": "MAX",
        "label": "MAX"
      }
    ]
  }
} );
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width : 100%;
  height  : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: if possible can you create jsfiddle, so that we can get idea of your code and data.  https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: also specify chart type

Comment: I can't really do jsfiddle because I can't give you access to the data from the file.
The chart type can be change but the error is still here.

Comment: I just ad a fiddle using the default exemple from amchart and the problem is still here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally,

in your example in `"categoryAxesSettings":` change `"startOnAxis"` to true

```
"categoryAxesSettings": {
    "equalSpacing": true,
    "gridColor": "#555",
    "gridAlpha": 1,
    "startOnAxis" : true,  // add this line
  },
```

follow this doc: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxis#startOnAxis

Comment: It's work pretty well but not for the chartScrollbar. I get the same spacing problem on this chart (only visible on short period data like on my picture)

Comment: Other related question is it possible to keep the space for the second chart?

Comment: honestly, I am no expert in charts, I just searched through the docs for this. and I worked on amcharts, so I am sure this is also possible. please check docs and if you are unable to find anything in docs, just email their support team, their support is good.